# How to use JQuery to show a specific button in a specific row

Tags: jquery

Okay so I have a webpage in HTML/PHP, and an external JS file.  I am trying to implement AJAX.  I have a table, each row has an edit button.  I want it so that when I click the edit button my cancel button show (which I have hidden) **for that row only.**

My thinking was If I used $(this).parent to select the parent of the clicked button (update) then added (".cancel").toggle();  it would only toggle the cancel button of the parent element of the clicked button.

I tried using this code,

```
$(".edit").click(function() {
    $(":text").prop('disabled', false);
    $(this).closest(".cancel").toggle();
    $("input[name=txtTeam]").hide();
    $.get("actionPages/updatePlayer.php", {
        player: ID
    }, function(response) {
        alert(response);
        location.reload();
    });
});
```

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Here is the relevant HTML

```
    $pTable .=  "<div class='row'>
                <div class='cell'>
                    <a class='delete'>Delete</a>
                    <a class='edit'>Edit</a>
                    <a class='cancel'>Cancel</a>
                </div>
                <div class='cell'><input disabled size='2' type='text' name='txtID' value='$ID'></div>
                <div class='cell'><input disabled size='25' type='text' name='txtFirst' value='$first'></div>
                <div class='cell'><input disabled size='25' type='text' name='txtLast' value='$last'></div>
                <div class='cell'><input disabled size='25' type='text' name='txtEmail' value='$email'></div>
                <div class='cell'><input disabled size='25' type='text' name='txtTeam' value='$team'></div>
            </div>";
```

I have a while loop setup to display each row but when I tried to paste it in it messed up the formatting.  Thanks.

Comment: show html mark up as well

Comment: Provide your html here

Answer (score 2):

Closest function query on closest parent! use following:

```
$(this).closest(".row").find(".cancel").toggle();
```

Answer (score 1):

[**closest()**](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) function searches up the DOM tree so supply ancestor of edit button

```
  $(this).closest(".cell").find('.delete').toggle();
  $(this).closest(".cell").find('.cancel').toggle();
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/4qzctb98/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below

HTML

```
  <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Hello</td>
        <td><input type="button" class="edit" value="Edit"/></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="canclebutton" value="Cancel"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Hello1</td>
        <td><input type="button" class="edit" value="Edit" /></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="canclebutton" value="Cancel" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Hello2</td>
        <td><input type="button" class="edit" value="Edit" /></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="canclebutton" value="Cancel" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Hello3</td>
        <td><input type="button" class="edit" value="Edit" /></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="canclebutton" value="Cancel" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Script

```
$(".canclebutton").hide();

$(".edit").click(function () {        
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.canclebutton').toggle();
    .
    .
    .
    .
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$pTable =  "<div class='row'><div class='cell'><a class='delete'>Delete</a><a class='edit'>Edit</a><a class='cancel'>Cancel</a></div><div class='cell'><input disabled size='2' type='text' name='txtID' value='$ID'></div><div class='cell'><input disabled size='25' type='text' name='txtFirst' value='$first'></div><div class='cell'><input disabled size='25' type='text' name='txtLast' value='$last'></div><div class='cell'><input disabled size='25' type='text' name='txtEmail' value='$email'></div><div class='cell'><input disabled size='25' type='text' name='txtTeam' value='$team'></div></div>";

$('#div').append($pTable)


$(document).on('click',".edit",function() {
    $(this).next(".cancel").toggle();
});
```

```css
.cancel{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='div'></div>
```

Since it is dynamically created delegate the event click to document use `.on()` then use `.next()` since the cancel is next to edit